# What is the Python numpy equivalent of the IDL # operator?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix-multiplication, idl-programming-language

I am looking for the Python `numpy` equivalent of the [IDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Data_Language) # operator.
Here is what the [# operator](http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/manipulating_arrays.html#arrays_3727706888_752395) does:

> Computes array elements by multiplying the columns of the first array
>   by the rows of the second array. The second array must have the same
>   number of columns as the first array has rows. The resulting array has
>   the same number of columns as the first array and the same number of
>   rows as the second array.

Here are the `numpy` arrays I am dealing with:

```
A = [[ 0.9826128   0.          0.18566662]
     [ 0.          1.          0.        ]
     [-0.18566662  0.          0.9826128 ]]
```

and

```
B = [[ 1.          0.          0.        ]
     [ 0.62692564  0.77418869  0.08715574]]
```

Also, `numpy.dot(A,B)` results in `ValueError: matrices are not aligned`.

Comment: You are thinking of the same row-column ordering as IDL. NumPy follows mathematical standards, the number of columns in the first matrix must equal the number of rows in the second matrix. Hence, the "strange" expression with all the transposes in it below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading the notes on IDL's definition of matrix multiplication, it seems they use the opposite notation to everyone else:

> IDL’s convention is to consider the first dimension to be the column
>   and the second dimension to be the row

So # can be achieved by the rather strange looking:

`numpy.dot(A.T, B.T).T`

from their example values:

```
import numpy as np
A =  np.array([[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5]])
B = np.array([[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]])
C = np.dot(A.T, B.T).T
print(C)
```

gives

```
[[ 3  4  5]
 [ 9 14 19]
 [15 24 33]]
```

Comment: `sharp = lambda x, y: np.dot(x.T, y.T).T` then `sharp(A, B)` for **IDL #**

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct you want [matrix multiplication](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html).

Comment: Not quite, because `numpy.dot(A,B)` results in `ValueError: matrices are not aligned`.